# Synonyms of Talk about

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I need some synonyms of talk about. 
For instance, “today I will talk about two topics.”

The context is the speaker at a conference is talking about three topics to the audience. It is a speech. I am sick of using "talk about" so I wanted to use another expression.

Right now, I am thinking of “express”, “address” or “deliver” but I am not sure whether they are desirable.
Could you please advise me?
I need some very formal words.
Thank you.

If this post has any problems, please let me know.

Comment: discuss two topics

Comment: *address, discuss, present, explore, cover, explain, review, consider, outline...* It's all pretty much a matter of opinion / stylistic choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much. Is “express or deliver two topics” awkward? I tried to google but I could not find enough examples.

Comment: "Talk about" can be used in a formal setting. Please provide more context so that we have a better picture of the nuance you're looking for.

Comment: 'Address two topics' is about as formal as it gets.

Comment: @Lawrence Hi, Lawrence. Thank you. The context is the speaker at a conference is talking about three topics to the audience in the introduction. It is a speech.  I am sick of using "talk about" so I wanted to use another expression. But maybe talk about is the best choice.

Comment: You deliver a speech, not a topic. Please look up the suggested terms in any online dictionary, and after that in a collocation dictionary. Try this one for starters http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=address and then http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/topic and https://www.foboko.com/dizionario-frase/inglese/topic

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you. The websites are very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest for "talk about", some of these:

- mention
- say something about
- point out
- bring up to your attention ...

If you have Word software, you may click or select the word and right-click to find a synonym.